# Call 2 methods through an argument in method in java

Tags: java, interface

I have 2 methods in interface:

```
public interface ISort
{
    public void insertionSort(final String[] a);
    public void selectionSort(final String[] a);
}
```

Let's call method, which receives method as an argument - Method B

First, I need to identify which interface method is called and call the corresponding interface method in the method B. The complexity is in certain functionality of Method B, which shall be completed by both of the interface methods. It means I need to have some temporary variable, which will encapsulate the required interface method call. All of the interface methods have the implementation.

```
public void runTest(ISort sort)
{
        String[] list=stringsFromFile();
        sort=sort.selectionSort(list);
        if(sort.toString().equals("insertionSort")){
            sort=sort.insertionSort(list);
        }

        sort(list)
}
```

I hope that the problem is clear. Since I have faced this issue, I have spent the whole day on finding the solution, but I couldn't find any and I am stuck.

Comment: Why do you need to do it like this?

Comment: `sort=sort.insertionSort(list);` makes no sense seeing how this is declared in `ISort`. It is a `void` method. It is not very clear.

Comment: If you use sort.toString there is no way that it equals to "insertionSort".

Comment: I don't see any other solution that would be suitable for my case because I need to call 2 methods, which has a considerably different implementation, in a "method B", but both of them need to have the same input in order to obtain the outcome of each method.

Comment: @davidxxx the code I currently have was just my attempt, but you are right it doesn't make sense in terms of the return type. However, I have tried to encapsulate it.

Comment: @Christian seems like, I need to create method, which checks the name and if equals will call corresponding method. You are right.

Comment: And why you never use `selectionSort()` ?

Comment: @davidxxx I didn't paste all of the code because it is a quite big one. For clarity, I have edited the code.

Comment: It means that you can invoke until 3 sorts one after the other : `selectionSort()` and `sort()` everytime and as a certain condition is encountered, `insertionSort()` too. It seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I came to the solution, which turns out to be really easy. I express my gratitude to everyone, who contributed to the solution of this nightmare, especially I want to say thanks to **@izilotti** and **@ruakh**, who showed me the right direction to solve my dilemma.

During debugging, I have found that literally nothing has been passed to runTest method, despite some class variables.

Solution: I just needed to pass the *class instance of SelectionSort or InsertionSort to runTest()* method.

Here it is:

```
public void main(){
    SelectionSort sorter=new SelectionSort();
    runTest(sorter);

    InsertionSort sorter2=new InsertionSort();
    runTest(sorter2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your interface should really have only a single method, `sort`. Insertion-sort and selection-sort are two implementations of the same 'sort' abstraction, and can be represented by different classes. Methods that call `sort` do not need to know which one they're calling:

```
public void runTest(final ISorter sorter) {
    final String[] array = stringsFromFile();
    sorter.sort(array);
    // TODO validate that the array is now sorted
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your idea more?

Comment: @Sean: Sure. I've added some code showing what `runTest` would look like now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having both sorting methods in the same interface, create one interface with a `void sort(final String[] a)` method and provide two different implementations for it, one for insertion sort and another, for selection sort.

```
public interface ISort {
    void sort(final String[] a);
}

public class SelectionSort implements ISort {
    @Override
    public void sort(final String[] a) {
        // Your implementation
    }
}

public class InsertionSort implements ISort {
    @Override
    public void sort(final String[] a) {
        // Your implementation
    }
}
```

The method calling runTest should pick the ISort implementation.

```
public void example() {
    ISort sorter = new SelectionSort();
    runTest(sorter);
}

public void runTest(ISort sort)
{
    String[] list = stringsFromFile();
    sort(list);
    // Use sorted array here
}
```

Comment: Yes, this what @ruakh suggested to do and I have done it, but there is strange problem, the runTest method does not see sort method, although I am passing it in argument

Comment: Are you using it in a static context?

Comment: What do you mean?